# OAuth Angular SPA code authorisation with .NET Core Web API

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core, oauth, azure-active-directory

Currently working on implementing AzureAD authentication into our .NET Core Web API. This needs to interact with an Angular 7 frontend, with an API on a different domain.

In a previous iteration of the application written in PHP, our authentication flow was:

1. Frontend redirects unauthenticated user to `<api host>/api/auth/login`
2. API would redirect the user to the AzureAD tenant login page
3. The user would login and be returned to the callback url, which is `<client host>/auth/login/callback?{oauth params}`
4. The client application would send an XHR to `<api host>/api/auth/login/callback?{oauth params}` and forward all of the OAuth GET params as is
5. If the supplied params authenticate successfully, the XHR response would contain a valid auth token

While some improvements could be made to this login flow, it worked pretty well and lets us manage sessions/tokens. The problem is getting the same flow to work with a .NET Core Web API.

The current issue is somewhat two-fold but:

We can't override the handler defined by `CallbackPath` on the `AddOAuth(...)` method. Ideally I'd like to return a JWT here on successful authentication so the client can consume it straight away. We can only override the return URL after the `AuthenticationMiddleware` finishes processing:

```
[HttpGet(nameof(Login))]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/api/auth/postcallback"
    }, "azuread");
}
```

`/api/auth/postcallback` in this case is just a controller which generates a JWT with the claims produced by a successful login:

```
[HttpGet(nameof(PostCallback))]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult PostCallback()
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["Tokens:Key"]);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(HttpContext.User.Claims),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(6),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return new JsonResult(new { token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token) });
}
```

In a browser, this will work fine. You'll sign in and then eventually land at a page which gives you a token you can use to authenticate, but we can't use that with an SPA because we have no way of getting the token back because we can't override the `CallbackPath` to redirect back to the client domain/url as it needs to be an absolute URL on the same domain.

I've set the authentication up as follows:

```
var auth = services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
auth.AddCookie();

auth.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromHours(6),
        ValidateLifetime = true
    };
});

auth.AddOAuth("azuread", opt =>
{
    opt.ClientId = Configuration["Auth:ClientId"];
    opt.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth:ClientSecret"];

    opt.CallbackPath = "/api/auth/callback";

    opt.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["Auth:AuthEndpoint"];
    opt.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["Auth:TokenEndpoint"];
    opt.UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["Auth:UserInformationEndpoint"];

    // claims/scopes/events removed from here
});
```

If you change the `CallbackPath` to something else and then manually visit the AzureAD login page with our client id, scopes and so on (but without a valid state/one generated by .NET Core), the callback below function will always fail silently, but if you then replace the `CallbackPath` with the regular value and refresh the page, keeping the state returned from AzureAD, you'll get an invalid state exception from the regular handler:

```
[HttpGet(nameof(Callback))]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(result.Principal);

    if(!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["Tokens:Key"]);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(HttpContext.User.Claims),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(6),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return new JsonResult(new { token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token) });
}
```

So, I have some questions:

1. Is there a way to generate a proper state from the web api (or the client) which will then validate successfully on the return and then we can use an XHR to sign in (assuming that is the issue), otherwise:
2. Is there another approach to authentication that allows us to do authorization code based oauth flow instead of an implicit oauth flow which seems to be how the typical AzureAD connectors work
3. Is this almost correct but I'm missing something critical which is causing the whole thing to fall down?

I've had a look at [.NET Core External Authentication without ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120508/net-core-external-authentication-without-asp-net-identity/) but haven't had much luck getting the same kind of idea to work based on that.

Comment: It is a bit late to ask, how did you solve the problem? I would like to implement a similar pattern and generate JWT locally.

Comment: @too vague recollection that there was a bit of a dirty hack with adding a handler into `OpenIdConnectEvents.OnRedirectToIdentity` and overwriting the `event.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri` which would correctly update auth state, but I remember there being a bunch of other trickery involved in there too. I would have to go digging to find it, but maybe that's enough to get you going